# Are the rep cap badges awarded based on upvotes only, or total rep for a day from any source?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

I may have just <del>hit</del> exceeded the reputation cap for the first time:

```
 -- 2010-12-11 rep +210  = 2221
```

When nothing popped up to tell me I'd been awarded the Mortarboard badge, I started wondering. I came to meta to see how these badges are calculated, but I've ended up just getting more confused.

It seems the rep limit rules were changed at some point, so I'm not sure now if the rep limit is based on upvotes only (i.e. get 20 upvotes on answers in a day) or rep from any source (for me, today, I have 120 rep from upvotes, and 90 rep from my 6 accepted answers - also a record for me).

Basically, I want to know if I'm going to get my badge, or if I need to find another 6 upvotes today. Also, when would this badge be awarded? Is it an end-of-the-day thing, or would it be immediate?

Comment: You *should* get the badge. If after 24 hours you haven't received the badge, then there may be a problem.

Comment: You have the badge at SO right now.

Comment: @Hans: Sweet! I guess it just took a couple hours before the system noticed.

Comment: So, because it isn't clear by the accepted answer, **Rep-Cap-Badges are awarded based on (total rep for day) >= 200** not only those from upvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually takes some time before the system notices your achievement and gives you your badge.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. I was just worried/annoyed because I worked hard to *finally* hit the rep cap, and then wasn't sure I had *actually* done it. It turns out I only hit the soft cap (200 from any source) that day, but still got the badge. I then went on to hit the hard cap (200 from upvotes only) the next day.